# Code generated by Record Espresso Test for recycler view throwing an exception

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I want to match the title of the recycler view with my custom text so, I used Android studio built in tool "Record Espresso Test", after adding an assertion when I try to run the test file it throws an exception. Following code is generated by Espresso Record tool

```
 @Test
  public void mainActivityTest() {
    ViewInteraction textView = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.title_text_view), withText("Making my way downtown, walking fast..."),
                    childAtPosition(
                            allOf(withId(R.id.post_parent_layout),
                                    childAtPosition(
                                    withId(R.id.posts_recycler_view),
                                            0)),2),isDisplayed()));
    textView.check(matches(withText("Making my way downtown, walking fast...")));

}

private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
        final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
            parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
            return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                    && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
        }
    };
}
```

************* Exception ***********************

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: com.rajasaboor.redditclient:id/user_name_text_view and with text: is "King_o" and Child at position 3 in parent (with id: 2131558575 and Child at position 0 in parent with id: 2131558533) and is displayed on the screen to the user)

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2560, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2392, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909287, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2296, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=96.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->FitWindowsLinearLayout{id=2131558503, res-name=action_bar_root, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2296, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ViewStubCompat{id=2131558504, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2296, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->ConstraintLayout{id=2131558529, res-name=main_parent_layout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2296, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+------>Toolbar{id=2131558530, res-name=toolbar_include, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=224, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+------->ProgressBar{id=2131558582, res-name=menu_progress_bar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=224, height=224, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=992.0, y=0.0}
|
+------->AppCompatTextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=457, height=107, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=64.0, y=58.0, text=Reddit Client, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------->ActionMenuView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=224, height=224, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=1216.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-------->ActionMenuItemView{id=2131558585, res-name=refresh_post_list_menu, desc=Refresh, visibility=VISIBLE, width=224, height=192, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=16.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=2131558531, res-name=no_offline_data_text_view, visibility=VISIBLE, width=774, height=97, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=333.0, y=1206.0, text=No offline data available, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>SwipeRefreshLayout{id=2131558532, res-name=swipe_layout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2072, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=224.0, child-count=2}
|
+------->CircleImageView{id=-1, visibility=GONE, width=160, height=160, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=640.0, y=-160.0}
|
+------->RecyclerView{id=2131558533, res-name=posts_recycler_view, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=2072, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+->View{id=16908336, res-name=navigationBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=2392.0}
|
+->View{id=16908335, res-name=statusBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=96, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1566)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at com.rajasaboor.redditclient.MainActivityTest.mainActivityTest(MainActivityTest.java:44)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1939)
```

Comment: Which exception is thrown? Can you please add it to your question by editing it?